# How to improve django/python processing speed

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

I need to improve the processing speed of this section of code:

```
    score_forms = InstrumentScore.objects.filter(instrument=study_obj.instrument)
    for administration_data_item in administration_data.objects.filter(administration_id=administration_id):
        inst = Instrument_Forms.objects.get(instrument=study_obj.instrument,itemID=administration_data_item.item_ID)
        scoring_category = inst.scoring_category if inst.scoring_category else inst.item_type
        for f in score_forms: #items can be counted under multiple Titles check category against all categories
            if f.kind == "count" :
                if scoring_category in f.category.split(';'):
                    if administration_data_item.value in f.measure.split(';'): #and check all values to see if we increment
                        scoring_dict[f.title] += 1
            else : 
                if scoring_category in f.category.split(';'):
                    scoring_dict[f.title] +=  administration_data_item.value + '\n'
```

The problem is it accesses many tables and the tables aren't always linked on a ForeignKey, instead they've been linked by giving a CharField that references the record in the other model.  How can I improve this processing without changing the database structure?

Models

```
class administration_data(models.Model):
    administration = models.ForeignKey("administration") # Associated administration
    item_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 101) # ID associated for each CDI item
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200) # Response given by participant to this particular item
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('administration', 'item_ID') # Each administation_data object must have a unique combination of administration ID and item ID.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.administration, self.item_ID)

class Instrument_Forms(models.Model):
    instrument = models.ForeignKey('researcher_UI.instrument', db_index=True)
    itemID = models.CharField(max_length = 101, db_index=True) # ID number for identification
    item = models.CharField(max_length = 101) # string variable name
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length = 101) # type of variable (word, phrase, etc.)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 101) # if word, the subcategory for item (animals, sounds, etc.)
    choices = models.ForeignKey('Choices', null=True, on_delete=models.deletion.PROTECT)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length = 1001, null=True, blank=True) # item listed in plaintext. This is what is displayed to test-takers along with possible choices
    gloss = models.CharField(max_length = 1001, null=True, blank=True) # English translation for item. At the moment, we only have English instruments so definition and gloss are identical
    complexity_category = models.CharField(max_length = 101, null=True, blank=True) # category for complexity item. Currently blank.
    uni_lemma = models.CharField(max_length= 101, null=True, blank=True) # ID for matching terms across languages. Currently unused.
    item_order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    scoring_category = models.CharField(max_length = 101, null=True, blank=True) # used to provide scoring granulatity - uses item_type if blank
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s, %s)" % (self.definition, self.instrument.verbose_name, self.itemID)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('instrument', 'itemID') # Each instrument in the database must have a unique combination of instrument and itemID

class InstrumentScore(models.Model):
    '''
    Class to store the instrument scoring mechanisms loaded from json files held in 
    /cdi_forms/form_data/scoring/
    '''
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(instrument, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=101)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=101)
    measure = models.CharField(max_length=101)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=999)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="count", choices=KIND_OPTIONS) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.instrument, self.title)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['instrument', 'order']

class instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51, primary_key=True) # Instrument short name
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length = 51, blank = True) # Instrument official title
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 51) # Instrument's language. For 'English Words & Sentences' this would be 'English'
    form = models.CharField(max_length = 51) # Instrument's form type abbreviation. For 'English Words & Sentences' this would be 'WS'
    min_age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Minimum age") # Minimum age in months that instrument was built for
    max_age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Maximum age") # Maximum age in months that instrument was built for
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s %s)" % (self.verbose_name, self.language, self.form)
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('language', 'form') # Each instrument in the database must have a unique combination of language and form type


class study(models.Model):
    researcher = models.ForeignKey("auth.user") # Researcher's name
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51) # Study name
    instrument = models.ForeignKey("instrument") # Instrument associated with study
    waiver = models.TextField(blank = True) # IRB Waiver of documentation for study or any additional instructions provided to participant
    study_group = models.CharField(max_length = 51, blank = True) # Study group
    anon_collection = models.BooleanField(default=False) # Whether participants in study will all be anonymous
    subject_cap = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null=True) # Subject cap to limit number of completed administrations
    confirm_completion = models.BooleanField(default=False) # Whether to have participant confirm child's age and that test was completed to best of ability at end of study
    allow_payment = models.BooleanField(default=False) # Whether to reward participants with gift card codes upon completion
    allow_sharing = models.BooleanField(default=False) # Whether to allow participants to share results via Facebook
    test_period = models.IntegerField(default=14, validators = [MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(28)]) # Number of days after test creation that a participant may work on and complete administration  
    prefilled_data = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    min_age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Minimum age", blank = True, null=True) # Minimum age in months for study
    max_age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Maximum age", blank = True, null=True) # Maximum age in months for study
    birth_weight_units = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default="lb")
    show_feedback = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Make a [mcve] and be specific. It's unlikely that anyone here will have take the time to analyze and profile your code. Where exactly do you want to speed up your code? It seems like your first code chunk could maybe be replaced by a single database query. But why is it implemented this way in the first place? Why not just use a foreign key, for example?

Comment: I don't know why a foreign key wasn't used originally, but it wasn't

Comment: That happens. :) But since we don't know this either, it makes it that much harder to suggest a proper solution. The logic here seems to me over complicated and a candidate for refactoring. If that's not an option, I would also consider just writing the query in raw SQL. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/. It's certainly going to be faster than the current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cut the time by 4 for the example data I am working with

```
for f in score_forms: #and ensure each score is at least 0
            insts = Instrument_Forms.objects.filter(instrument=study_obj.instrument, scoring_category__in=f.category.split(';'))
            insts_IDs = []
            for inst in insts: insts_IDs.append(inst.itemID)
            if f.kind == 'count' : 
                scoring_dict[f.title] = administration_data.objects.filter(administration_id=administration_id, value__in=f.measure.split(';'), item_ID__in=insts_IDs).count()
            else : 
                items = administration_data.objects.filter(administration_id=administration_id, item_ID__in=insts_IDs)
                scoring_dict[f.title] = ''
                for item in items :
                    scoring_dict[f.title] +=  item.value + '\n'
```